# Who is Panama Oxridge?

Tags: real, treasure-hunt

Panama Oxridge is the author of a children's book series about a boy called Justin Thyme. However, the name Panama Oxridge is actually a pseudonym for an *unknown* author. From [the series website](http://www.justinthyme.info/page104.html):

> Once a well-known author of picture-puzzle books, “Panama Oxridge” accidentally stumbled across the secret of time travel and, ever since, has been forced to adopt a pseudonym, wear a series of disguises, and move house thirteen times.
>
> However, for obscure legal reasons, Panama Oxridge’s real name has been hidden somewhere on this web site. To discover his or her true identity, you will need to follow a perplexing trail of clues and ignore all the red herrings!

Some instructions follow on how to solve the first level of this puzzle, but I haven't managed to get all the way yet. Having come across this puzzle on [Literature SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1170/17), I thought it would also make a fun challenge for Puzzling SE.

**How is this puzzle to be solved? What is Panama Oxridge's real name?**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Following on from [Rand al'Thor's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52911/445)...

### Level Three

Our next challenge can be found...

> ... [on this page](http://justinthyme.info/page130.html) (from MIRANDA OXPAGE):
>
>  **Automatic Element Inventory Ordering Unit**
>  Three of the bottles in Justin’s chemical cupboard are almost empty. To reach the next level, you must use this machine to re-order the correct three elements. On twelve of the secret pages you will find numbered element bottles. The chemical cupboard is on the thirteenth hidden page; use it to convert the element numbers to letters), then rearrange the letters to spell out the three specific elements you need to order here, using the bottle colours (green, blue and pink) as clues.

The hidden page is...

> [The chemical cupboard here](http://justinthyme.info/page129.html) from PAMANGRA OXIDE, which gives us the atomic numbers, names and symbols of the first 101 chemical elements.

The remaining pages give the ingredients we need:

> MAXARA PIDGEON ([page 118](http://justinthyme.info/page118.html)): Green bottle, element 7 (N, Nitrogen)
>  ADRIAN POXMAGE ([page 119](http://justinthyme.info/page119.html)): Green bottle, element 37 (Rb, Rubidium)
>  AMANDA OXGRIPE ([page 120](http://justinthyme.info/page120.html)): Blue bottle, element 6 (C, Carbon)
>  PARADOX ENIGMA ([page 121](http://justinthyme.info/page121.html)): Pink bottle, element 73 (Ta, Tantalum)
>  PAIGE RANDOMAX ([page 122](http://justinthyme.info/page122.html)): Pink bottle, element 22 (Ti, Titanium)
>  MADIGAN AXROPE ([page 123](http://justinthyme.info/page123.html)): Pink bottle, element 10 (Ne, Neon)
>  MADOX PEAGRAIN ([page 124](http://justinthyme.info/page124.html)): Green bottle, element 20 (Ca, Calcium)
>  MARGO PAXIDEAN ([page 125](http://justinthyme.info/page125.html)): Green bottle, element 8 (O, Oxygen)
>  DORIAN MAXPAGE ([page 126](http://justinthyme.info/page126.html)): Blue bottle, element 18 (Ar, Argon)
>  MAXGRADE PIANO ([page 127](http://justinthyme.info/page127.html)): Blue bottle, element 28 (Ni, Nickel)
>  OXINGAM PARADE ([page 128](http://justinthyme.info/page128.html)): Pink bottle, element 33 (As, Arsenic)
>  MIRANDA OXPAGE ([page 130](http://justinthyme.info/page130.html)): Blue bottle, element 34 (Se, Selenium)

Or more compactly:

> Green: n rb ca o
>  Blue: c ar ni se
>  Pink: ta ti ne as

Rearranging:

> Green: carbon
>  Blue: arsenic
>  Pink: astatine
>
>  Entering the above in the [A.E.I.O.U. machine](http://justinthyme.info/page130.html) leads to [this page](http://justinthyme.info/page131.html).

### Level Four

> [**Memory Test**](http://justinthyme.info/page131.html)
>  Whilst exploring this web site I collected 32 items ... however, there are only 31 of them in this box to the right, and 31 in the box below.
>
>  Can you work out which **two different** items are missing (one in each box) & have been replaced by question marks?
>
>  The difficulty is you can never see ALL the items at once!
>
>  Once you have identified the two missing items, click [HERE](http://justinthyme.info/page117.html) to return to the first password page.
>
>  Using lower case letters only, enter the two words in (alphabetical order) to access the next level. This test is good practice - (you’re going to need a really excellent memory to complete the next level!)

This level is a fairly simple exercise, and following the instructions gives the answer

> banana / frog (which we enter at [this previous password page](http://justinthyme.info/page117.html), leading to [this page](http://justinthyme.info/page116.html))

### Level Five

> [**Eliza's Bubble Puzzle**](http://justinthyme.info/page116.html)
>  Somewhere on the pages you have already visited are letters that spell out the next password (and numbers to help you arrange them in the correct order).
>
>  Maybe you’ve spotted some already - if not, the images in Eliza’s bubbles should help you locate them ... but you’ll need a sharp eye and a good memory to discover them all.
>
>  Once again, you are seeking a two-part password name. The first name has eight letters; the surname has just three letters.

Looking back and using the pictures provided as hints, we find what we need:

> [14W](http://justinthyme.info/page112.html): 1D (coin in bottom right)
>  [MAXGRADE PIANO page](http://justinthyme.info/page127.html): 2A (toy block in bottom left)
>  [ADRIAN POXMAGE page](http://justinthyme.info/page119.html): E3 (monitor in top left)
>  [20C](http://justinthyme.info/page77.html): D4 (cars under bed)
>  [43A](http://justinthyme.info/page84.html): A5 (camera unit)
>  [34E](http://justinthyme.info/page83.html): A10 L6 (car license plate)
>  [28C](http://justinthyme.info/page78.html): U7 (top blackboard)
>  [15O](http://justinthyme.info/page115.html): S8 (paper at rightmost edge)
>  [MADOX PEAGRAIN page](http://justinthyme.info/page124.html): H9 (pencil in bottom left)
>  [40A](http://justinthyme.info/page85.html): P11 (parking sign)

Using the enumeration, this gives the answer as

> daedalus hap (which we once again enter at [this password page](http://justinthyme.info/page117.html), leading to [here](http://justinthyme.info/page133.html))

### Level Six

> [**One Last Anagram!**](http://justinthyme.info/page133.html)
>  A curious name with mysterious origins ...
>
>  D??????? was a mythological Athenian architect and inventor, famed for building a labyrinth (a puzzling maze) for King Minos. Desperate to escape the Isle of Crete, he used wax and feathers to make wings for himself and his son - but the boy ignored his father’s warning and flew too close to the sun, which melted the wax holding his feathers in place. As a result, he fell into the Aegean sea and drowned, while his father flew to safety!
>
>  H?? has two meanings. Firstly, it is an old Norse word for *chance* or luck. It is the root of the word happen (as in *to happen upon* something by chance), appenstance (another archaic word for *chance*), and haphazard (meaning *random* or by chance). Its secondary meaning is a Scottish dialect term meaning *to cover up*.
>
>  The ideal name for someone who just *happens* to *cover up* his or her identity by means of a *labyrinthine puzzle!* This peculiar name is an anagram of Panama Oxridge’s real name. Simply rearrange the letters using these 4 easy rules:
>    1) Only the 3 identical vowels remain where they are.
>    2) The first and last letters swap places ... and so do the 4th and 6th letters.
>    3) The remaining consonants move back one place each
>    4) Finally, place the remaining vowels in reverse alphabetical order.
>
>  To check your answer, use THIS password box. If you are correct, you will be taken to a page where the first letter of each sentence spells out the author’s name!

Following the instructions, we learn the true name of Panama Oxridge:

> `DAEDALUSHAP`
>  `?A??A????A?` (3 identical vowels remain)
>  `PA?LAD???AD` (first <-> last, 4th <-> 6th)
>  `PA?LADSH?AD` (remaining consonants back one)
>  `PAULADSHEAD` (remaining vowels in reverse alphabetical order)
>
>  Answer: paul adshead

Submitting this answer takes us to

> [26L](http://justinthyme.info/page103.html), which indeed hides Panama Oxridge's true name via the first letter of each sentence!

Comment: I don't really get what it says on that 26L page :( I guess I will ever know the true name :(

Comment: @Totumus Maximus The first letter of each sentence spells out Paul Adshead. Ex. "Panama Oxridge is an enigma." (P), "Although born in 1960..." (A), "Unusually, this paradoxical author’s..." (U) and so on.

Comment: @Demesne ah i was trying to do hard and got confused i guess. Thanks :)

Comment: @Sp3000 *So*... Paula D' Shea?

Comment: @Totumus Maximus No problem.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine you forgot the D in the boxed sentence.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus Ah.. Paul Adshead - a man?

Answer (score 17):

**Partial answer**

### **Level One**

> Start by running your cursor over the Thyme clan badge in the bottom left-hand corner of 47 web pages. Each one will reveal a different number and a letter of the alphabet. Simply write the letters in numerical order to discover your first clue.

I managed to find all of the pages with alphanumeric clues. It took *hours*. Here's a list:

> [1T](http://www.justinthyme.info/page104.html)
>  [2O](http://www.justinthyme.info/page69.html)
>  [3F](http://www.justinthyme.info/page71.html)
>  [4I](http://www.justinthyme.info/page72.html)
>  [5N](http://www.justinthyme.info/page79.html)
>  [6D](http://www.justinthyme.info/page87.html)
>  [7T](http://www.justinthyme.info/page91.html)
>  [8H](http://www.justinthyme.info/page92.html)
>  [9E](http://www.justinthyme.info/page97.html)
>  [10P](http://www.justinthyme.info/page96.html)
>  [11A](http://www.justinthyme.info/page98.html)
>  [12S](http://www.justinthyme.info/page109.html)
>  [13S](http://www.justinthyme.info/page110.html)
>  [14W](http://www.justinthyme.info/page112.html)
>  [15O](http://www.justinthyme.info/page115.html)
>  [16R](http://www.justinthyme.info/page114.html)
>  [17D](http://www.justinthyme.info/page70.html)
>  [18M](http://www.justinthyme.info/page73.html)
>  [19A](http://www.justinthyme.info/page76.html)
>  [20C](http://www.justinthyme.info/page77.html)
>  [21H](http://www.justinthyme.info/page80.html)
>  [22I](http://www.justinthyme.info/page86.html)
>  [23N](http://www.justinthyme.info/page88.html)
>  [24E](http://www.justinthyme.info/page90.html)
>  [25C](http://www.justinthyme.info/page100.html)
>  [26L](http://www.justinthyme.info/page103.html)
>  [27I](http://www.justinthyme.info/page111.html)
>  [28C](http://www.justinthyme.info/page78.html)
>  [29K](http://www.justinthyme.info/page108.html)
>  [30O](http://www.justinthyme.info/page74.html)
>  [31N](http://www.justinthyme.info/page75.html)
>  [32T](http://www.justinthyme.info/page81.html)
>  [33H](http://www.justinthyme.info/page113.html)
>  [34E](http://www.justinthyme.info/page83.html)
>  [35E](http://www.justinthyme.info/page94.html)
>  [36Y](http://www.justinthyme.info/page67.html)
>  [37E](http://www.justinthyme.info/page93.html)
>  [38O](http://www.justinthyme.info/page89.html)
>  [39F](http://www.justinthyme.info/page95.html)
>  [40A](http://www.justinthyme.info/page85.html)
>  [41P](http://www.justinthyme.info/page105.html)
>  [42E](http://www.justinthyme.info/page99.html)
>  [43A](http://www.justinthyme.info/page84.html)
>  [44C](http://www.justinthyme.info/page107.html)
>  [45O](http://www.justinthyme.info/page82.html)
>  [46C](http://www.justinthyme.info/page102.html)
>  [47K](http://www.justinthyme.info/page68.html)

Fortunately it didn't take me ***too*** long to remember which of these pages had a

> peacock in it. Clicking on the peacock's eye on [this page](http://www.justinthyme.info/page113.html) takes us [here](http://www.justinthyme.info/page117.html) and to Level Two.

### **Level Two**

> Congratulations! You have found the password page. From here you can access 13 top secret pages ... but first you must find the 13 passwords you will need.
>
> Each password is an anagram of “Panama Oxridge”. [...] All 13 anagrams can be found somewhere in the pictures on this web site, (the first is in this >>>> picture). Perhaps you’ve noticed it already.
>
> Each password has two parts - usually (but not always) a Christian name and a surname. Type the first half of the password in the top box, and the 2nd part of the password in the bottom box - then click login.
>
> Avoid guessing. There are hundreds of anagrams of “Panama Oxridge” - but only the ones found at this web site will work!

Here are the anagrams we've managed to find so far:

- > on [that same page](http://www.justinthyme.info/page117.html), PARADOX ENIGMA, which takes us to [this new page](http://justinthyme.info/page121.html)
- > on the [3F page](http://www.justinthyme.info/page71.html), PAMANGRA OXIDE, which takes us to [this new page](http://justinthyme.info/page129.html) (thanks @Ankoganit)
- > on the [6D page](http://www.justinthyme.info/page87.html), ADRIAN POXMAGE, which takes us to [this new page](http://justinthyme.info/page119.html) (thanks @Ankoganit)
- > on the [11A page](http://www.justinthyme.info/page98.html), MAXGRADE PIANO, which takes us to [this page](http://justinthyme.info/page127.html) (thanks @Wen1now)
- > on the [16R page](http://www.justinthyme.info/page114.html), MIRANDA OXPAGE, which takes us to [this page](http://justinthyme.info/page130.html) (thanks @Wen1now)
- > on the [17D page](http://www.justinthyme.info/page70.html), MADIGAN AXROPE, which takes us to [this page](http://justinthyme.info/page123.html) (thanks @Wen1now)
- > on the [33H page](http://www.justinthyme.info/page113.html), MAXARA PIDGEON, which takes us to [this page](http://justinthyme.info/page118.html) (thanks @Wen1now)
- > on the [40A page](http://www.justinthyme.info/page85.html), OXINGAM PARADE, which takes us to [this page](http://justinthyme.info/page128.html) (thanks @Ankoganit)

Four more still to find, and then we can start putting together the info and clues on the new pages!

Comment: MAXGRADE PIANO on 11A (pg98)

Comment: MIRANDA OXPAGE on 16R (pg114)

Comment: MAXARA PIDGEON on 33H (pg113)

Comment: MADIGAN AXROPE on 17D (pg70)

Comment: MADOX PEAGRAIN on 28C (page 78).

Comment: MARGO PAXIDEAN on 29K (page 108).

Comment: PAIGE RANDOMAX on 46C (page 102).

Comment: DORIAN MAXPAGE on 20C (page 77).

Comment: AMANDA OXGRIPE on 30O (page 74)

Comment: You should copy this and add it to my question on literarure

Comment: "There are hundreds of anagrams of “Panama Oxridge”..." wins understatement of the month. ;)

Comment: @MartinEnder Even reasonably meaningful anagrams?

Comment: @Randal'Thor That'll be hard to quantify, but even if we just go with pronounceable ones I'd still expect you'd end up with millions.